# numpy equivalent code of unsqueeze and expand from torch tensor method

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor, torch

I have these 2 tensors

```
box_a = torch.randn(1,4)
box_b = torch.randn(1,4)
```

and i have a code in pytorch

```
box_a[:, 2:].unsqueeze(1).expand(1, 1, 2)
```

but i want to convert the above code in numpy
for `box_a` and `box_b` i can do something like this

```
  box_a = numpy.random.randn(1,4)
  box_b = numpy.random.randn(1,4)
```

But what about this

```
box_a[:, 2:].unsqueeze(1).expand(1, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Pretty sure this'll do it too:

`box_a[:, None, 2:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved it

```
box_a = np.random.randn(1,4)
box_b = np.random.randn(1,4)
max_xy = np.broadcast_to(np.expand_dims(box_a[:, 2:],axis=1),(1,1,2))
```